# iOS app having background mode support for location tracking auto closed after some times (not in every session)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, ios12

Our app using location tracking in background mode but after minimize the "applicationwillterminate:" method called after 20 to 50 minutes. Its happened only sometimes not every time.

Answer (score 0):

Use background task with a [expiration handler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/extending_your_app_s_background_execution_time). Check for [`backgroundTimeRemaining`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623029-backgroundtimeremaining?language=objc) and call `endBackgroundTask(_:)` when you get location data.

> If you do not end your tasks in a timely manner, the system terminates your app.

Use background task as described in [Updating Your App with Background App Refresh](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/updating_your_app_with_background_app_refresh), to update the data opportunistically.

Comment: Thanks..But we are using background modes for location updates so dont need to use background fetch.